# What happened to everyone's magical abilities?

Tags: society, magic

The setting: a remote pre-industrial port city.

The basic premise: As long as anyone can remember, the residents of the city have exhibited magical powers. The city had become fairly large as increasing numbers of merchants and travelers settled there and began to acquire the same magical abilities themselves. The source of the magic wasn't generally known, but nevertheless it provided the residents of the city a prosperous and fulfilling life.

Then one day the magic suddenly vanishes. Generations have passed without a memory of life before magic, and the society is completely unprepared to take care of itself without it. There is a little bit of violence and unrest, but mostly the citizens are paralyzed by helplessness and then hopelessness.

What kind of magical abilities make sense for this scenario? What is a plausible source of the magic, and how can it be restored?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a grasp of what our community is about. The way you phrased your question doesn't sound like a worldbuilding problem, rather a plot development for your story with some task to guess what you have in mind. This sort of question is not a good fit here, please rework it.

Comment: I'm afraid @L.Dutch is right.  Your story sounds interesting but we're not a place to get story ideas.  If you have a focused question about worldbuilding, we're all ears.

Comment: Howdy Daniel.  I hope it makes sense, but building an entire magic system in one question is a bit too broad.  Indeed, raw idea generation doesn't work well on this site because it's designed to help you solve specific problems that can be represented by a single best answer.  Can you [edit] your question to narrow this down and take it one step at a time?

Comment: Yeah everybody, that makes sense. I'll see if I can rework the question.

Comment: I see the edit but you need to focus on a single question (esp when one is basically "what entire magic system do I use?". Might I suggest you ask this in [our Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) then edit this based on the feedback you recieve there?